# Being terminated and last paycheck

Tags: termination

I see in California law that an employer has to give the final paycheck to a terminated employer within 72 hours. I was let go from a part time job where I worked 6 hours a week. I was let go and wasn’t paid my final paycheck until about a month after. Does anyone know if this is legal?

Comment: We are not lawyers. The way you have presented this makes it seem illegal, but we don’t know the facts of the situation or the law(s) in question. Go ask a California lawyer.

Comment: Legal or not, what do you hope to gain here? If you want money, that'll probably come down to attaching a monetary value to any losses suffered. Did not having the money significantly affect your life (to the point that a court could justify a 5- or 6-figure payout)?

Answer (score 11):

At this stage, does it really matter? You've been paid, get the cheque into the bank and move on. The only people who are going to win from you doing anything else are the lawyers.